# Workflow on creation modifies the item

Tags: workflow, library

In a library I have a problem with a workflow triggered on creation. The workflow simply sends an email to a user and does not modify the documents neither the meta-information, but when I upload a document and have filled the requested info in the popup form, I get an error that the document has been modified by myself.

Does anybody knows a workaround for this?

Some picture to make it clear:
[image: At file loading I have the meta info form....]

But at saving...
[image]

On request I am adding also the workflow picture. 
[image]

Comment: I have understood that the workflow itself is changing the meta-information on its column "WorkflowName" at the very beginning. I have tried deleting this column but it made workflow loosing its connection with the list... it runs forever without conclusion. :(

Comment: how have u built your workflow? can we have a look at it (picture)?

Comment: Yes. Adding WF pitcure in the Body, but I don't think it helps. Any workflow would have the same effect

Comment: Change it to be an on change workflow instead of an on creation and you'll be all set

Comment: Eric, I need this to be run on new items, otherwise I would have done it differently!

Answer (score 2):

I Have found the solution. And it is very trivial...
It's enough to prevent the Workflow writing the stage name! So I just had to untick this
[image]
...and my workflow does not change the item anymore!
Can anybody sign this as solution? I cannot do it for it is my own answer...

Answer (score 0):

Make it go into a loop that will wait X minutes until there is a Main-Category added, that way it won't change anything until after people have uploaded and set the metadata.

Comment: This was the aim I had when giving the pause, but the problem is that when any WF is started - even if it just loops - a column is changed in the item...